# Streaming from iCloud?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, streaming, icloud-api

Is it possible to recreate a scenario like itunes match with iCloud APIs available to-date (i am writing/editing this in april 2012) .. specifically..I mean something like this>

A user creates a media document (audio or video) in my app...and it is automatically uploaded to (his) iCloud space. Then user decides to delete his local copy. But the app still shows the document in let say a table view...and if the user presses play..it begins to stream from iCloud..The user also is able to recreate (download) a local copy of the document. (Just to be sure, I understand the difference between the document I describe here and the concept of UIDocument).
If yes..how would I implement the transfer of the file ..let say a recording of 1 minute video..to the cloud? What folder would it be?

Answer (score 1):

Apple docs state that there shouldnt be a distinction between where the data is stored. No sense of local copy of cloud copy. I think it is possible to do what you ask, but you're likely to get rejected. Use something like amazon AWS for hosting instead. You'd have more control over the files and unless you're going to have tons of users, you'll also qualify for the free tier.

Comment: I'd still be interested in hints about technical implementation (NSFilePresenter and NSFileCoordinator?). 
I'd be willing to risk a rejection, just for the sake of learning the CD framework and how to do it.
Thanks also for the Amazon suggestion, I'l take a look at it.